# Apply style properties to my PDF

Tags: html, jsp, pdf-generation

I am generating a PDF file using the JSP in that I want to apply CSS style properties, but it is not working.  The PDF appears normally no style properties are applied.

In the following example, I add green color background for body tag but in the pdf the green color is not showing. It is showing an plain html only.

Please suggest me any appropriate solution for this issue.

```
Document document = new Document();

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/pdf_generation/pdfGeneration10.pdf");

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fileOutputStream);

document.open();

HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);

String html = "<html><head></head><body style='background-color:green'><P> THIS IS SAMPLE ONE</p><table><tr><td>Demo and new be the way to go sdfsdf sdfdf</td></tr></table></body></html>";

StyleSheet styleSheet  = new StyleSheet();

htmlWorker.setStyleSheet(styleSheet);

htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(html));

document.close();
```

Comment: (1) HTMLWorker has been deprecated in favor of XML Worker. (2) You're creating a `StyleSheet` object, but you're not adding any styles to that object (hence: no styles are applied).

Comment: Okay after I searched in the google I used the XML worker to applying the styles for html and some styles are working. But margin, input fields, border is not working. Please suggest me what I need to do.